# Clean way to get foreign key objects in PHP MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, many-to-many

I use the following code to get a book object from my MySQL database.

```
$q = $pdo->prepare('SELECT 
                        book_id "id", 
                        book_title "title", 
                        book_slug "slug"
                    FROM book 
                    WHERE book_id=:id');
$q->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->execute();
$book = $q->fetchObject('Book');
```

Books have a many-to-many relation to songs, which have a `song_id`, `song_title` and `song_lyrics`, so I have a book_song table with `book_id` and `song_id`.

I'd like to get all the songs belonging to a book. Is there a clean way to do this in one query?

What I'm looking for here is how to write the query in a clean way and also how to process the results to end up with a Book object which has an array of Song objects without too much code.

Comment: Mmmm....you mean a single query to retrive all the songs belonging to a book....why dont you use a join statement?

Comment: with PDO use fetchall to create your associative array http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: You surely don't mean an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Of course using a JOIN would be part of it. What I'm wondering is how to write the SQL and the PHP to do this in as clean a way as possible.

Comment: @gillyspy Already using fetchAll to get a list of books or songs or whatever, but I'm talking about foreign keys here which I don't think fetchAll does anything about.

Comment: `select book_id, song_id, song_title, song_lyrics  from book join book_song on book_song.book_id = book.book_id join song on book_song.song_id = song.song_id order by book_id, song_id`

Comment: @gillyspy And how would you process the results so you end up with a single Book object with an array of Song objects?

Answer (score 2):

The JOIN that gillyspy suggested would be how an ORM would handle this, but if you're using just PDO, then you have to handle all the mappings yourself (and the looping, and detecting when to create a new object, etc.) This looks to me like you've crossed the threshold where it makes sense to consider an ORM framework (such as http://www.phpactiverecord.org/). If you add even one more one-to-many association, the mappings are going to make your brain hurt.